# Firefox Bookmarks on Ubuntu 12.04 Start Page

Tags: 12.04, firefox, browser, bookmarks

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 Lt. The Ubuntu Start Page is Firefox Browser, but has no 'bookmarks' Icon showing? How do I 'bookmark' sites for future re-call? How do I download or place the many bookmarks I have, from the 'xp' machine Ubuntu is replacing? I reviewed all the postings suggested, but could not find answer. I'm a Novice.

Answer (score 0):

### Different ways to use bookmarks on Firefox :

#### A) Bookmark's menu

- Drag your mouse to the top of the screen, the black menu-bar will change
- Click on "Bookmark", the usual bookmark's menu will open.

---

#### B) Personnal toolbar

- Drag your mouse to the top of the screen, the black menu-bar will change
- Click on "View" > "Toolbar" and activate 'personnal toolbar' where you will be able to drag&drop tabs.

---

#### C) Keyboard shortcuts

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to open the Bookmark's Library
- On any website, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to add the page to bookmarks.

Comment: Mr Vaykadji,
Wonderful - Thank You Ever So Much - Why the Documentation does not provide this great 'clue' is a mystery. Again - Thanks-Thanks.

Know doubt I will ask any future questions of you, until I'm comfortable with program.